# Weight paint mode wont paint on the mesh

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, vertex-weights

So i downloaded this fully rigged model from blendswap,

and i made adjustments to the model in edit mode, i using the knife too made some cut to imitate that of a shoe to the model and thought that i would weightpaint on manually if the weights are not applied to the new vertices.

back in pose mode.. i pose the rig and confirm that the new vetrices did not get the corresponding weight of their neighboring verteces automatically, so i enter the weight paint mode to fix it and

the weight paint wont draw anything, none of the brushes work, i cant get to fix it!!
here is how it looks
[image: those two vertices are the ones i created]

[here is the .blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7fkkzfq5qG1Y0lOZ0lDNlZpRnM/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to select which vertices you need to paint first then paint them. So select the vertices as shown below using `shift + right mouse click`, then paint them using `left mouse click`. Updated `.blend` file can be found [here](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=44132).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

choose the whole mesh and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* and remove all the doubles and try again.